# Getting index of object without using ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was wondering  is there any other way to get index of an object except using `ng-click` in angularjs. I am using `ng-repeat` to display object and I don't need `ng-click` option, but I need `$index` of that object. Of course I need to pass that index in controller

Comment: how are you planning on **selecting** that object?

Comment: kindly clarify the use case so as to tell you the solution what you want to use instead of ngClick.

Comment: Not sure how you're going to select the object, but if you have an issue with ng-click specifically, you can use (click) or (change), its the same event though.

Comment: have you tried mouse events of angular?

Comment: you can pass multiple functions in ng-click, incase you're using it already for something else, because I don't understand any other reason why you don't want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your requirement . 
But still you can try something like below. But it's not good idea to do so. Because every time view updates this **getIndexFunction** will execute.

If you want based on user interaction, passing on event function is the only possible way

```
<li ng-repeat="x in records">
   {{getIndexFunction($index , x)}}
</li>
```